# Divide the image into 4x4 blocks and Counts the number of Black/White Pixels in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a binary 512x512 pixel image that I want to divide into 4 x 4 pixels of blocks and counts the number the number of black colour pixel in a block. If the sum of black colour pixel in a block is even, the corresponding block is assigned a value of 0. Otherwise, the value is 1. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to load the picture as a numpy array and then create two loops for x dimension and y dimension with offset of 4. This is my suggestion:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = plt.imread('myplot1.png')
image = np.array(image)
image = image[:,:,1] #if RGB

print(image.shape)


for x in np.arange(0,image.shape[0]):
    for y in np.arange(image.shape[1]):
        if x+4 < image.shape[0] and y+4 < image.shape[1]:
            sum = np.sum(image[x:x+4,y:y+4])
            if sum > 4:
                image[x:x + 4, y:y + 4] = 1
            elif sum < 4:
                image[x:x + 4, y:y + 4] = 0
```